# PIP framework, Not found error

Tags: php, config, base-url

My PIP PHP framework was doing fine, then I messed something up: I don't know what it is.  Basically for every controller except my default, I get a 404 not found error.  If I change the default to a different page, the new page will work fine, but no others will.  I can't seem to find any information in the logs.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to trace the route apache is using to find the new page.  Or if there are any logs I can check.  My local log.txt within the framework shows nothing.  Apache log shows nothing.  PHP log shows nothing.

I thought it may have something to do with the base_url, but no matter how I change it, my controllers are still not found.

```
 $config['base_url'] = ''; // Base URL including trailing slash (e.g. http://localhost/)
```

Is there any way to see the absolute path that apache/ my browser is trying to take when I load localhost/controller?  Something that would show me file://Applications/MAMP/htdocs/path/to/controller, even if the page doesn't load?  Is there somewhere in the config/sys file that I can show that info?

Not sure why it was downgraded.  I thought I gave all the information I had about the problem and just looking for how to troubleshoot a 404 not found when my default_controller loads.

Weird!  I downloaded a new copy of PIP, copied all the files from my old copy to my new copy, and then now it works.  It must have been some directory thing with Apache.

Comment: We need to see some code --- amp up your error reporting: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1); --- and have you tried throwing in any die() statements? Also, are you using xdebug?

Comment: The page is not found at all.  Where would I put in a die() statement?  If the page isn't found then I assume none of the code on the page will run.  Error reporting works fine if the page is found.

Comment: Is the "Not found" error from Apache or from your framework? Do you have a custom set of `mod_rewrite` rules to power this? If so, please add them here.

Comment: I assume it's from the framework, as pages outside of the directory framework load and the default_controller page loads.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xdebug.  I'll have a look.

Comment: You are better of using Zannel

Answer (score 0):

if you have apache running, set the base url to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

// remember the forward slash at the end.

if that still does not do it, go to your MVC framework folder, and replace the index.php and the system folder and all its content, you can take a back up if you want of this folder before you do so,
The there are two files that will mess with the routing

```
index.php
pip.php
```

so if your config base url is set as the example above and the controllers are still not found it is one of these two files that have been modified.

// note, you might also want to check the .htaccess file for mod_rewrite which needs to be enabled.